# ubuntu 12.04 is not showing on system start up?

Tags: software-center

i already installed windows first and then installed linux mint12. The boot screen is changed to grub, and is first showing linux mint loading and then windows at last. today i installed ubuntu 12.04 and installed along side with windows and is not showing on boot menu. can any body helps me?

Answer (score 2):

Welcome Sreenath! Run the `Ubuntu live cd`,mount the drive where you installed Ubuntu(running `Gparted` application help you to see where is Ubuntu)and open a `terminal(Cntrl+Alt+T open a terminal`).Type this command `Sudo update-grub`.If it ask you to be root,then type `sudo -i` and run the previous command.Reboot your system and it should work.